# How to access database for Pepper

Tags: python, pepper

I did some object detection and I have problem for recognation them.I guess its about database problem.How can I access them? When I reopen Cherographe it doesnt recognation image which I detect before. I use this for access them; C:\Users\pcname\AppData\Roaming\naoqi\vision\visionrecognition\backup

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Users\pcname\AppData\Roaming\naoqi\vision\visionrecognition\backup` is on your computer, not on Pepper, so there is no way Pepper will access that. According to [the documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/vision/alvisionrecognition.html), the database is at `/home/nao/naoqi/.local/share/naoqi/vision/visionrecognition/`, but usually you shouldn't need to access it directly, just use the ALVisionRecognition API.